# Intersect Parallel Lines with Orthogonal 2D Grid

Tags: algorithm, geometry, intersection

I have two parallel lines that can go in any direction.  They are guaranteed not to be the same.

I have a 2D grid (with non-integer coordinates from 0.0 to 1.0, but I suspect this can be solved by scaling the whole problem), aligned orthogonally in the usual way.

I need an algorithm that generates a list of all squares with any area between the two lines.

My current algorithm is woefully inefficient (represents the two lines as a rotated rectangle, and then tests polygon-polygon intersection on every square).  It works, but it's horrifically slow.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the direction and position of the two lines then you can use the [Bresenham line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to calculate all the 'squares' that will be 'touched' by either of the lines. It will be a simple job to add the in-between squares. If the two lines are separated by an integral number of 'squares' then you will only have to solve Bresenham for one of them, but if they have non-integral separation you will have to solve for both of them (the latter would also work even if the lines were non parallel).

Comment: Bresenham's algorithm doesn't return every square the line intersects.  Also, while there are other algorithms that do, finding the in-between squares isn't actually trivial--I was hoping for an algorithm that makes use of the fact that we know a priori that there are two lines.